# How to delete updraft wordpress plugin with files of that plugin?

Tags: wordpress

when it installed in a domain but not working for some unknown reason then simply delete the plugin and re-installed it but now it also the same situation it's not working even it not change its settings also.

Comment: In my experience, plugins are only in effect if activated or exist in the plugins folder. In the plugins/ folder, you should be able to delete the updraft/ folder with no effect to the Wordpress site.

Comment: Ok, but when it will be reinstall then it automatically configured as the previous setting. and it aging not working.

Comment: You might try reaching out to support: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/updraftplus/